# Erro ao testar uma sessao

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer com que o meu login dependendo do que acontecer na parte interna do PHP eu avise se é o email, ou se o usuário está bloqueado, estou desenvolvendo isso tudo em PHP, utilizando mínimo possível de javascript. Porém, a primeira vez que roda o site funciona, na segunda quando erra o login propriamente não.

Segue os códigos.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    include 'scripts/help.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>JR Tela de login</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="js/principal01.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" id="from" name="form" method="POST" action="scripts/validacao.php">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">JR Comunicações</h2>

            <div id="msg"><?php 
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['msg']); die;

                if (isset($_SESSION)) {
                    get_msg('msg_login');
                }else{
                    echo "";
                }

                ?></div>


            <input type="text" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Senha">
            <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**help.php**

```
<?php
// Função para setar a mensagem
function set_msg($id, $msg, $tipo)
{
    session_start();

    if (isset($id)) {
       $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
       switch ($tipo) {

        case 'error':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-danger">' . $msg . '</div>';

            break;

        case 'alert':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-alert">' . $msg . '</div>';

            break;

        default:
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-alert">' . $msg . '</div>';
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Esta função vai exibir sua mensagem onde você quiser
function get_msg($id) { 
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['msg']); die;

        session_start();      

        if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) {

         if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {

          echo $_SESSION['msg']; 

            }

        return FALSE; 
        } 

}

?>
```

**validacao.php**

```
<?php

include ("../includes/conexao.php");
include("help.php");

$email = ($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']);
$senha = ($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT COD_IDENT_USUAR, TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR FROM tbl_USUARIOS WHERE TXT_ENDER_EMAIL = '".$email."' AND TXT_SENHA_USUAR = '".$senha."'";
$qr = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($qr) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    set_msg('msg_login', 'Login ou senha inválidos', 'error');
    header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);


    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['COD_IDENT_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioEmail'] = $resultado['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioFlag'] = $resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'];

    if($resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'] == 'A'){
    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: ../paginas/principal.php"); exit;
    }else{
        set_msg('msg_login', 'Usuario bloqueado', 'error');
        header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Amigo não vou responder claramente, pois me parece que o problema é no seu entendimento na hora de desenvolver, mas posso lhe dar alguma dicas: No momento que você usa `session_start` a variavel super global `$_SESSION` já está disponivel, portanto `isset($_SESSION)` não tem sentido. `if (isset($id)) {` dentro da função `set_msg` também não tem sentido (exceto pela questão de `NULL`)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não está funcionando quando peço para dar isset($_SESSION), e na primeira vez que eu rodei a pagina, porem depois que cliquei em submit, ele vai e me vem com a sessao montada e os valores setados.

Comment: Eu preciso de quando ele voltar do submit ele apareça na tela, tentei fazer   desta forma, porem ele acusa que a sessao ta invalida, se caso eu seto um valor para ele ele fica da mesma maneira, so aparecendo um valor

Comment: Renan eu não te dei a solução, eu te informei que o uso de alguns `isset`s e da variável `$_SESSION` estão errado (sem lógica ou necessidade), não estou lhe criticando, estou apenas lhe dizendo que não faz sentido/necessidade da maneira que você colocou no código e ao meu ver o código em si só é um problema por causa do seu entendimento (ou falta dele) sobre o uso das **super-globais** (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) e da função `isset` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) e por mais que eu possa lhe ajudar a corrigir o código, o problema vai além disto.

Comment: Mais me ajude almenos encontrar o erro, eu rodo, tento testo mais nao consigo..

Comment: Não consegue, por que o código não tem lógica (sem querer ofender), o uso da variável superglobal chamada `$_SESSION` e de alguns `isset`s, me desculpe, não é má vontade minha, apenas estou lhe dando a prévia de onde você pode encontrar o problema, já que não é um problema necessariamente do seu código, mas sim do seu entendimento das superglobais+isset. Talvez algum outro colaborador forneça uma resposta mais clara. Mas o caminho para a solução é você entender o `isset` e a variavel `$_SESSION`. Vou reforçar: ... [leia o proximo comentário]

Comment: continuação]... isset($_SESSION) não tem lógica/necessidade - if (isset($id)) { não tem lógica/necessidade. Uma dica a mais, remova o session_start de dentro das funções e coloque ele no topo do arquivo help.php e mova a linha `<?php 
    include 'scripts/help.php';
?>` para antes do DOCTYPE. Isto provavelmente já irá resolver parte do problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, lembre sempre de postar a maior quantidade de detalhes possíveis, por exemplo:

- Os trechos de códigos importantes
- Como o seu código deveria funcionar e como está funcionando
- Os erros ocorridos (não algo como: não funcionou, deu pau, nada acontece)
- Qualquer dependência e/ou lib que você utilize e ache relevante

---

## Resposta

Em poucas palavras a solução para o seu problema é iniciar a sessão no inicio de todo arquivo e/ou layout que você tiver, ou neste caso, ao menos no **index.php**.

Mas para um entendimento melhor, peço que veja os tópicos abaixo:

## session_start( );

Inicie a sessão no inicio de todo arquivo, e não somente na sua função. Dessa forma você pode acessar os itens da sessão de qualquer forma, e não somente dentro da sua função onde você estava iniciando a sessão.

Sendo assim, seu código ficaria assim:

**index.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'scripts/help.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

**help.php:**

```
<?php
// Função para setar a mensagem
function set_msg($id, $msg, $tipo)
{
    if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) {

     if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
```

**validacao.php:**

```
<?php session_start();

include ("../includes/conexao.php");
include("help.php");

// REMOVA esse código
// Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
// if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

#### Observação [update]

Assim com o [@guilherme-nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) também mencionou, retire o `session_start()` de dentro do seu arquivo `help.php` e deixe somente no `index.php` e no `validation.php`.

O arquivo `help.php` até então é utilizado apenas para manter suas funções úteis, e como ele está incluído no `index.php` **a sessão é compartilhada**.

### isset( )

Também conforme mencionado pelo [@guilherme-nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento), não há a necessidade de você checar a existência da `$_SESSION`, visando que você já "startou/iniciou" ela.

Portanto, você deve verificar apenas se o **indice/chave/key/valor** que você deseja existe na sessão, ou seja:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['msg_login'])) {
        get_msg('msg_login');
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
?>
</div>
```

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário abaixo.

Comment: Só mais uns detalhes se quiser adicionar a resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68757/erro-ao-testar-uma-sessao#comment140411_68757 (note que o problema do "código" do autor vai além disto)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionado :)